# Auth repeats controller in URL

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, authorization

I am setting for the first time the Auth component on my site, and everything seems to work fine except when I try to access a restricted page. Instead of being redirected to `http://localhost/MySite/users/login`, I get redirected to `http://localhost/MySite/users/users/login`, the controller name is repeated on the url. How can this issue be fixed?

I am using CakePhp 2.4.4

**AppController**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar',
                            'Session','Auth' => array(
                                        'loginRedirect'=> array(
                                            'controller' => 'admins',
                                            'action' => 'admin_index'
                                        ),
                                        'logoutRedirect' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'users',
                                            'action' => 'login' 
                                        ),
                                        'loginAction' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'users',
                                            'action' => 'login',
                                            'plugin' => 'users'
                                        ),
                                        'authError' => 'Não tem permissão para aceder a esta área. Por favor faça login.',
                                        'authenticate' => array(
                                            'Form' => array(
                                                'fields' => array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password'
                                                    ),
                                                'userModel' => 'User'
                                            )
                                        ),
                                        'authorize' =>array('Controller'
                                        )
                                    )
                        );

public function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->allow('index','ShowImages','ShowShowbill','ShowVideos','ShowContactUs','contact','login','DisplayMusic','DisplayEntertainment','DisplayPromotion','DisplayStaff','DisplayEquipments');

}
```

Comment: In loginAction, try removing `'plugin' => 'users'`

Comment: @Kai Awesome, thanks! What does`'plugin'` actually do to Auth?

Comment: It does the same as any time you use the CakePHP way of defining URL's -- it's telling it that your loginAction is part of a plugin.  CakePHP plugins are almost like dropping an independent CakePHP application into your Plugin folder, for the purposes of reusing code.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html

Comment: Protip: It is recommended to use [vhost setup](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/29/working-with-domains-locally/) to work with your domains locally - and to avoid "localhost" domain URLs.

Comment: Protip: It is recommended to use [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) to work locally. Then you work on `http://localhost/` as you root, making the above obsolete :). But I agree with Mark, avoid directories, it causes major headaches which are difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

In Auth component you need to add 'unauthorizedRedirect' otherwise Cake tries to redirect to /{app-directory} (this was giving me a headache yesterday).

```
public $components = array(
    //your other components
    'Auth' => array(
        //your other options for Auth
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => '/home'
    )
);
```

This would direct any user trying to access a page they shouldn't be allowed on to 'yourDomain/home'.