# How to authorize user that tries to login

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, authorization

I am using Auth for the first time and everytime I try to login, using the correct credentials, the login fails and I get the action login failure error message. How can I "mark" the user as an allowed user, to have access to the pages with prefix `admin`?

I am using CakePhp 2.4.4

**AppController**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar',
                            'Session','Auth' => array(
                                        'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false),
                                        'logoutAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout', 'admin' => false),
                                        'loginRedirect'=> '/admin',
                                        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false),
                                        'authError' => 'Não tem permissão para aceder a esta área. Por favor faça login.',
                                        'authenticate' => array(
                                            'Form' => array(
                                                'fields' => array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password'
                                                    ),
                                                'userModel' => 'User'
                                            )
                                        )//,
                                        //'authorize' =>array('Controller'),
                                        //'passwordHasher' => array(
                                        //  'className' => 'Simple',
                                        //  'hashType' => 'sha1'
                                        //)
                                    )
                                    /*,'Auth' => array(
                                                'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'admin_index'),
                                                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'),
                                                'authorize' => array('Controller')
                                                )*/
                        );

public function beforeFilter(){
    if($this->isPrefix('admin')){

            if($this->isAuthorized('admin')){
                if($this->Session->check('Auth.User.group_id')){
                    if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.group_id')==1){
                        //authorizes user to access pages with admin prefix
                    }else{
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Você não tem permissão para acessar essa URL'));
                        $this->Redirect('/login');
                    }
                }else{
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Você não tem permissão para acessar essa URL'));
                        $this->Redirect('/login');
                    }
            }else{
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Você não tem permissão para acessar essa URL'));
                        $this->Redirect('/login');
                    }   

        //$this->layout='admin';
    }else{
        $this->Auth->allow('index','ShowImages','ShowShowbill','ShowVideos','ShowContactUs','contact','login','DisplayMusic','DisplayEntertainment','DisplayPromotion','DisplayStaff','DisplayEquipments');

    }
    /*if($this->isPrefix('admin')){
        if($this->Auth->loggedIn()){
            if($this->Session->check('Auth.User.group_id')){
                if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.group_id')==1){

                }else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Você não tem permissão para acessar essa URL'));
                    $this->Redirect('/');
                }
            }
        }
        $this->layout='admin';
    }else{
        $this->Auth->allow('index','ShowImages','ShowShowbill','ShowVideos','ShowContactUs','contact','login','DisplayMusic','DisplayEntertainment','DisplayPromotion','DisplayStaff','DisplayEquipments');

    }*/
    //$this->Auth->allow('index','ShowImages','ShowShowbill','ShowVideos','ShowContactUs','login','ShowContactUs','timthumb');
    //$this->Auth->allow('image');
}
public function isPrefix($prefix) {
return isset($this->request->params['prefix']) && $this->request->params['prefix'] == $prefix;
}
public function isAuthorized($user){
    if(isset($user['role'])&&$user['role']==='admin'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public $helpers = array('Html' ,
                        'Form' ,
                        'Timthumb.Timthumb',
                        'Paginator', 
                        'Session',
                        'Js',
                        'Fancybox.Fancybox',
                        'Paginator',
                        );
```

}

**UsersController**

```
    public function login(){
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            //$user = array('User' => array('username'=> $this->request->data['User']['username'],'password'=> $this->request->data['User']['password']));
            //debug(AuthComponent::user($this->data[$this->alias]['username']));
            //debug(AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']));

            if($this->Auth->login()){
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(
                    __('O nome de utilizador ou a password estão incorrectos.'),
                    'default',array(),
                    'auth'
                    );
            }
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
<style>
#authMessage{
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #b94a48;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}
#flashMessage{
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
     color: #b94a48;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #eed3d7;
}
</style>
<h2>Login</h2>
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Session->flash();?>
<div class="users form">

<?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo "<div class=\"alert alert-info\">Por favor insira um nome de Administrador e a password.</div>"; ?></legend>
    <?php 
      echo $this->Form->input('username');
      echo $this->Form->input('password');
?>
</fieldset>
<?php   
    echo $this->Form->submit(__('Login'), array('class' => 'btn btn-success','formnovalidate' => true)) ;
      echo $this->Form->end();
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auth repeats controller in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477660/auth-repeats-controller-in-url)

Comment: @burzum well that question is mine, and that was fixed by removing `'plugin'` from the Auth configuration. Can this issue be caused by some of teh configs in AppController as well?

Comment: @burzum I updated my question, is it valid now?

Answer (score 0):

Correct and working code has be:

```
public function login() {
 if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'),'flash_error', array(), 'auth');
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: `$this->Auth->redirect()` was used prior version 2.3, according to the cake documentation. I am using 2.4.4.